# python script not starting with etc/rc.local

Tags: python, linux, startup

I created a python script that I would like to execute at each startup. I modified the `etc/rc.local`, but I don't get the script to run.

`etc/rc.local` addition (I added the sleep thinking it may help):

```
(sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mower-gps-tracking/app/gps_logger.py)&
```

imports in the different python scripts (I don't know if it matters):

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import serial
import time
import threading
from gpiozero import LED, Button
```

When I start the `etc/rc.local` manually via a `ssh` command, it runs fine.

Any idea what I'm missing ?

Comment: Recent versions of Linux no longer run the `/etc/rc.local` script. You may need to use `systemd` or `crontab`. Have a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Systemd is working fine, thank you for the tip John Anderson

Comment: Most often when same command is not running in /etc/rc.local it's a simple problem of changes in Environment, mainly PATH or in this case python specific environment variables, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the script (rc.local) is executable ie. has the 'x' attribute set.

And you will probably need a

#!/bin/bash

as line #1 of your script.

Hope this helps.
And as per Barmar above, probably more approp in the Unix forums.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my linux box no issues .. As a test create a script that will wrap your script, have it write to a tmp file so you can see if it actually runs. Use nohup and & in your scripts.

/etc/rc.local:

```
nohup /root/script.sh &
```

/root/script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm starting something .." > /tmp/startup_thing.log
/root/gps_logger.py
```

note: all scripts need to be chmod a+x file.ext. if it's not running check for the file /tmp/startup_thing.log . If it's there then you have some other issue. If it isn't then rc.local isn't working.